# Wrap Elements on X number Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I want numbers of DIV elements with the same classes, and on load, Jquery will be able to wrap certain number of those DIV elements.

Example:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>

</div>
```

Then let say i want to wrap every 4 DIV elements with another div called `childWrapper`

Result should be:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="childWrapper">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="childWrapper">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I know I've answered this before, just can't remember how to find it.

Comment: Maybe if the questioner posted the code he tried, it would help you remember.

Comment: I see a `wrapAll()` answer coming soon!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8822504/6782

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
function wrapDivs(number) {
    var divs = $("div.wrapper > div.child");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=number) {
        divs.slice(i, i+number).wrapAll("<div class='childWrapper'></div>");
    }
}
```

The parameter for this function is the number of divs you want in each `childWrapper`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/eqFQF/2/

Answer (score 0):

To wrap every 4 elements into another container you can do the following.

```
// for every direct .child inside .wrapper
$(".wrapper > .child").each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(i % 4 == 0) { // if boundary element
        $('<div class="wrap2" />')
            .append($this.nextUntil(':eq('+(i+3)+')')) // append next 3 into the interim wrapper
            .prepend($this).appendTo('.wrapper'); // prepend this element  
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9cEE/)**